# Problem implementing jQuery Real Person Captcha

Tags: jquery, captcha

I'm using this captcha in one of my forms: http://keith-wood.name/realPersonRef.html

Right now, I'm having a problem with fonts *around* the captcha.

Take a look:

[image]

The font of "Click to Change" (a link that the plugin created) and the font of "I agree..." (which I created) changes to some weird thin font that changes back to normal when I highlight it (as demonstrated).

The plugin uses a monospace font to generate and align the dots to look like letters/numbers.

Maybe it's a browser issue (I'm using latest Chrome on latest OS X)?

Any help?